# How to find maximum value of given functions?

Tags: calculus

In this question,which was asked in our exam.It is given that for each continuous function f:[0,1]->R.Let I(f)=$\int_{0}^{1}x^2f(x)dx$ and J(f)=$\int_{0}^{1}x(f(x))^2dx$.Then find max value of I(f)-J(f).I thought that a definite integral is always a constant which means I(f) and j(f) are constant which means max value of $I(f)-J(f)=\int_{0}^{1}xf(x)(x-f(x))dx$ but after this I was stuck since I cannot find function f with given information.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\Phi(f) = \int_0^1 -x (f(x))^2 + x^2 f(x)$. Then, variational derivative is
$$ \Phi'(f; h) := \frac d{dt} \Phi(f + th)|_{t=0} = \int_0^1 (-2xf(x) + x^2) h(x). $$ 
It vanishes for all $h$ if and only if $-2xf(x)+x^2 = 0$. That is, if $f(x) = \frac{x}2$.

Now, $\Phi$ is concave (as $\Phi''(f; h) = \int_0^1 -2xh(x)^2 \le 0$). Thus, $f(x) = \frac{x}2$ is the maximizer of $\Phi$.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

$ f $ is continuous at $ [0,1] $, thus it is bounded and there exist $ (a,b)\in [0,1] $ such that
$$\inf_{[0,1]}f=f(a)=m \;$$
 and$$ \; \sup_{[0,1]}f=f(b)=M$$
then

$$I(f)\le M\int_0^1x^2dx$$
and
$$-J(f)\le -\min(m^2,M^2)\int_0^1xdx$$

Comment: what do you mean by inf and sup?I dont know about these functions.